# Enable selection for a DataList in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, datalist

When we add a gridview we can enable selecting a row by checked enable selection on grid view proerty. But When we add DataList there is not 'enable selection' property for that.

Is any way to do this?
I want to bind a datalist with a table of my database and select a row to access row items or delete a row like gridview.

Please give me a sample codes .

Thanks alot.

Comment: 4 questions in 15minutes. have you tried to do anything yourself lately? google still exists i remind you.

Comment: I am new user in today. I don't know how many question can I send. I am worked on a project today and have some questions about that. excuse me.

Comment: @ub1k I think there is no limit of how many questions you can ask in 15minutes. Is there any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23559/Working-with-the-DataList-Control